# Install python3.11 on centos stream 9

Tags: python, centos, redhat, yum, python-3.11

I am trying to install python 3.11.3 version on centos stream 9 distro.
centos stream 9 has default below python versions installed.
root@ip-*.*.*.* ~]# python --version

Python 3.9.16

[root@ip-*.*.*.* ~]# python3 --version

Python 3.9.16

[root@ip-*.*.*.* ~]# python3.9 --version

Python 3.9.16

Below are steps to install python 3.11.3 version -

yum install -y gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel zlib-devel wget make

wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.3/Python-3.11.3.tgz

tar xzf Python-3.11.3.tgz

cd Python-3.11.3 && sudo ./configure

make install

but once I update python3 link using below command, yum seems to be broken. Not sure what wrong I am doing here.

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/local/bin/python3.11 1

**Error -
-bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory**

So, how should I link (command) python3 with python3.11.3 version?
Also, should I be doing altinstallation (make altinstall) rather than make install here ?

Link python3 with python3.11.3 version.
Tried with command
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/local/bin/python3.11 1

but it seems to breaking yum.

Comment: Do you want to link the `python` command to `python3.11`, or do you just want to install Python 3.11 and maybe call it with `python3.11` ?

Comment: I want to link python3 with python3.11.

Comment: Ok. I will do alt installation. what difference it would make ? Currently, with make install, it is installing in /usr/local/bin directory which is different than system python directory which is /usr/bin/. Also, how should I link python3 with python3.11 version?